# How do I use the GUI to search for files in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, 12.04, search

On the command line I regularly use **locate**, or more often a `locate x | grep y` pattern to find a file I know exists but can't find!

I'd like something that did this quickly in the GUI. Can't find it if it's there.

Here's my confusion

- In the applications/overview I can see **Search and Indexing**. This seems to be a configuration tool. But if this is a server, I can't find a client.
- In applications I find Nepomuk File Indexing -- I think this is a KDE thing? Ditto, no client?
- I've installed tracker. This is a strange mix of powerful and unreliable/limited. e.g. it doesn't find files like locate does (returns no results where locate returns 96 results), but is will unpack every tag I've added to my photos! And you can't limit by folder for a quick search within a folder.
- The old Gnome 2 Search for files... thing is not in the Accessories menu anymore.

I feel that this is basic/core-level functionality and I can't help feeling I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I think you are looking for `gnome-search-tool` which was removed in 12.04 unfortunately for the price of integrated Tracker, AFAIK. I guess you can access it from Nautilus and Dash, but I'm not sure. Not great decision, as search syntax for Tracker is awful, IMHO. Try searching repository for `gnome-search-tool`

Comment: How is tracker  integrated? into what? Overview? How to use it?

Comment: I don't know the details. If you want to know tracker syntax google for `tracker sparql`, which I have no idea if you can use in 12.04 (Nautilus/Dash where this feature is implemented). Better download `gnome-search-tool` and do your searches like you are used to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this.

1. Open **Files** and click the *Search* button. This is the easiest and recommended choice since it's installed by default.
2. Or you can install [gnome-search-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-search-tool) [image: Install gnome-search-tool]
3. Or you can install [tracker-gui](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/tracker-gui) [image: Install tracker-gui]

Comment: Thanks for answering. **1 works for filenames** but does not appear to be using an index. **2 works but** does not appear to be using an index (at least not for content searches, based on a 15 minute search I just did!) but has a lot of filter options. **3 doesn't work** - fails to find basic filename substring matches.

Comment: +1 for the gnome-search-tool, a very intuitive way to search for a novice in linux(ubuntu). The 1-st (default) option is awful.

Comment: @artfulrobot run first `tracker-preferences` so setup and start tracker index service. Look similar to [the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher).

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for this myself as I find Unity too slow (Ubuntu 12.10). Best thing I've found so far is [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to activate once installed.

Comment: I think This only searches recent documents by name as it used Zeitgeist.

Comment: No Synapse searches everything. Really good, works a bit odd in Kubuntu, but fine in Ubuntu...

Answer (score 2):

### [Catfish](https://launchpad.net/catfish-search)

You can also install `catfish` package (written in Python):

> Catfish is a search GUI powered by **locate** and **find** behind the scenes, with **autocompletion** from Zeitgeist and locate. The advanced options allow **filtering by date and file type**. The interface is intentionally lightweight and simple, using only GTK+.

[image: screenshot]

#### References

- [Official site](https://launchpad.net/catfish-search) (on Launchpad)
- [Catfish on Two Toasts](http://www.twotoasts.de/index.php/catfish/)

Comment: Simple and lightweight, seems to use `locate` first and then `find`, so it combines indexed and non-indexed search... looks great so far

Answer (score 0):

You can install

```
apt install searchmonkey
```

If you want to use it in Thunar:

- open `Edit` > `Configure custom actions`
- Click on the `+` sign to open a new child window
- In the tab titled `Basic`, enter `Search for files` in the Name box
- In the `Command` box, enter `searchmonkey -d %f` or choose something from the command parameters provided

Then open the `Appearance Conditions` tab. In there, enter `*` as the File Pattern and tick the appropriate choice below `Appears if selection contains:`

Click `OK`. Close the `Custom Actions` window.

You should see the option `Search for files` when you click on `File` in Thunar's menu bar now.