# Find file by content - Simple GUI-based solution

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gui, search

I'm looking for a GUI way to search for a textfile file by content on Ubuntu precise/Gnome 3 (i.e. find all "*.rb" files which contain the word "script" in "~/Documents" and subdirectories).

I know I can use grep, but I'm looking for a simple GUI solution. If possible no tools that have their own daemons and/or build huge indexes in advance - a simple, iterative, on-demand search would be the best.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [How do I use the GUI to search for files in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111580/how-do-i-use-the-gui-to-search-for-files-in-gnome).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't gnome-search-tool work?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. It wasn't installed by default and I didn't know it existed. Thankyou.