# Gnome Search Tool - Open Containing Folder does nothing : 16.04 flashback

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, gnome-classic

The containing folder does not open when I right click and select [Open Containing Folder] from a set of search results in **Gnome Search Tool**.

As requested: screenshot of how I am attempting to open folder:

[image]

- I get an hourglass (the circular one)
- I have a panel entry showing [ opening etc. ]

But these both disappear, without Nautilus opening in the correct folder.

---

Config:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Gnome Flashback
- Compiz

Any ideas ?

---

Update:

I ran gnome-search-tool in a terminal.

These are the error messages I see after the fail.

```
  (nautilus:26807): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

  (nautilus:26807): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

  (nautilus:26807): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

  (nautilus:26807): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

  (nautilus:26807): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Comment: How did you try opening it? Can you give a screenshot?

Comment: @Anwar : Added the screenshot as requested - thanks for the interest.

Comment: Added an answer. Check it

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug of `gnome-search-tool`. Here is the report https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671317

The exact behaviour of this bug is, without opening the containing directory, it opens the file directly. I installed this program and verified the bug's behaviour.

In your case, it's not opening any file. It could be because it can't find the default application associated with the file type.

You can do two things:

1. Reporting this bug against gnome-search-tool package of Ubuntu here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-search-tool/+bugs. (If you report, let me know in the comment so that I can click affect me option. If you decide not to report, I would do later)
2. Use some other GUI search tools for Ubuntu. Here are some suggestion:

   - [How do I use the GUI to search for files in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111580/how-do-i-use-the-gui-to-search-for-files-in-gnome)
   - Or you can use catfish which is very similar to gnome-search-tool

     ```
     sudo apt-get install catfish
     ```

Hope that will help.

Comment: My default file associations are solid - I can open the file(s) directly with a <RightClick> [open]. That bug report applies also to older Ubuntu versions - I was all good on 14.04. What I found useful in the (working version) of gnome-search-tool was being able to find multiple files of the same name and then select multiple results and open all containing folders with one click. Made it very easy to examine locations and contents to tidy things up. I'll try **catfish** when I am back at work. Thanks.

Comment: @TaoRich I tested it on 16.04. The bug reports and my test are same. You might want to check with other kind of file type. I hope you good luck on __catfish__

Comment: @TaoRich have you tested catfish?

Comment: Yes thanks for the suggestion ... installed yesterday. Pretty slick and does most of what I used to be able to do with gnome-search-tool. Just a pity it doesn't have a file type column in the search results. I've now got both catfish and gnome-search installed and will use each one for different reasons.

Comment: @TaoRich Glad that it helped :)